# Anyone that had the aol oauth api working?

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, oauth, aol

i'm developing an application with multiple login and information export options like yahoo, google contacts, live contacts etc. I tried to do the oauth wrapper for aol, followed the examples in the http://dev.aol.com/api/openauth page but it doesnt works.

I just only wanted to know if there is anyone that chad succeeded with its specs and got some sample code working, i tried and got the token in response but when i try to do an api request i get the response : `Key Used From unauthenticated site`

does it have to run in a online server? do i have to get some rsa signed file on my server?

any hint is welcome, thank you very much!

Comment: could you paste your code, even if it's quite long ?

Comment: the example provided by developers wont work : http://dev.aol.com/api/openauth

Comment: @FrederikEychenié sorry i cant put my code here, i signed a NDA with a company, so i risk myself to get filed for a court demmand. anyways the code were much similar that the one in the aol examples, more oop but the main idea were there. Thanks anyways.

Comment: which codebase are you following from this link? http://dev.aol.com/api/openauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for my late response, have being little busy here. The code in the example finally worked right last time i tried, maybe their servers had some issues or i misconfigured the example, not sure, but in my project it didnt worked, finally i managed the solution by using the CURLOPT_REFERER parameter i found in the example. I am sure that it was the issue in my code, because i was testing in a devel environment with a .loc top level domain.

Finally i want to give a hint to all the people trying to develop 3rd party apps that check the validity of the urls asking for permissions, you could use a testing environment by using the CURLOPT_REFERER paramater by setting the production url you want in the testing environment.

**file in the testing environment `http://www.mycoolsite.loc`.**

```
curl_setopt( CURLOPT_REFERER 'http://www.mycoolsite.com' );
```

The site that will receive the answer will check the referer and assume the .com one instead the .loc

Thanks to everybody that tried to help me.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that i'm unable to post the code, i signed a NDA contract so the company is now the owner of the code. Anyways i could help you with any issue that you have with your code, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that i can't event log in in AOL dev site , so i don't have any code as there is no documentation available to perform this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it before but I think you have to tell them your the IP you will sent requests from..

I was making project over enom API and I had to send them my IP to authorize my API requests

Comment: I downloaded the sample code "Buddy List" and it worked fine
http://dev.aol.com/gallery_files/buddylist_php.zip

Comment: Could you please post here the server response? mine is as follow :  
`Your Buddy List
Bad getInfo statusCode of: 44
getInfo failed
Curses, presence status=440

Th-th-th-that's all folks (for now) `

Watch out for the getInfo command failed

Comment: Your Buddy List

    Bad getInfo statusCode of: 20
    getInfo failed
    
    Group: Buddies
    Group: Family
    Group: Co-Workers
    
    Th-th-th-that's all folks (for now)

I think I get this error "getInfo failed" because I have none in my list